# Security rule for an object within a document

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have the following collections

/companies

/users

Within the user document I have a companyUuid to reference its company membership and an object called permissions that has two attributes:

```
{ 
  admin : true|false
  superAdmin: true | false
}
```

My app logic is as follows:

- Superadmins can do anything, including granting superadmin or admin permission to other users
- Admins can only grant admin access to other users with the same companyUuid
- Non-admins cannot grant any admin permissions
- Admins should not remove admin permissions on themselves.

My concern is, given that I store the permissions within the user document, how do I effectively prevent non-Admins from writing to their permissions object while also allowing them to edit the fields within the user document?

I have some code here, it looks way too complicated I think, there has to be a simpler way. I would greatly appreciate if you point me in the right direction:

```
  match /users/{userUuid} { 

      allow read: if request.auth != null && belongsToSameCompany()

      function areAdminPermissionsIntact(){
        return request.resource.permissions.admin == resource.permissions.admin
      }

      function areSuperAdminPermissionsIntact(){
        return request.resource.permissions.superAdmin == resource.permissions.superAdmin
      }

      function isNotTheSameUser(){
        return resource.data.uuid != request.auth.uid
      }

       function belongsToSameCompany(){
        return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.companyUuid == resource.data.companyUuid    
      }

      allow write: if request.auth != null 
        && 
       (areAdminPermissionsIntact() || areAdminPermissionsIntact() == false && resource.data.permissions.admin == true && isNotTheSameUser() && belongsToSameCompany()) 
        &&    
       (areSuperAdminPermissionsIntact() || areSuperAdminPermissionsIntact() == false && resource.data.permissions.superAdmin == true && isNotTheSameUser() && belongsToSameCompany())
    }
```

Comment: Alternatively, I considered a different approach, after reading Dough's article https://medium.com/firebase-developers/patterns-for-security-with-firebase-group-based-permissions-for-cloud-firestore-72859cdec8f6
I created two separate collections to track permissions
admins/userUuid/companyUuid
and
superAdmins/userUuid
Then, added an admins array to the company's document, and subsequently added a trigger to keep the admins collection in sync. Then, on the company's collection added a write security rule to only allow admins to edit company's info, including permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really get any simpler than this.  You have to check that the fields that should not change are not changing, and that's exactly what you're doing here.

You could express this a bit differently using the [MapDiff API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.MapDiff) to check the list of fields that are unchanged between the request and resource, but honestly, it's not going to make this any less complicated.

Comment: thank you greatly @Doug, you like always, saving people' lives, lol